# How to change a button Name in Rails_Admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

I wanted to change the name of few buttons in my project which uses Rails_admin.

```
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base     
    has_many  :table_management
    has_many :dishes
end
```

So here in the view am getting buttons with name as
    "Add a new Dish" , "Add a new Table management" .
  I wanted to change these name inside the buttons. Can some one help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Udaykumardas  Thankyou, I was already on that! Didn't get the solution yet!

Comment: @Udaykumardas couldn't get anything !

Comment: you should use jquery in the view file with field's id to change the text.It will be easy.